Why doesn't the Rambam disqualify Yushkuh as Moshiach because he's not descended from King David?
B"H
The Rambam writes:

4 If a king will arise from the House of David who diligently
contemplates the Torah and observes its mitzvot as prescribed by the
Written Law and the Oral Law as David, his ancestor, will compel all
of Israel to walk in (the way of the Torah) and rectify the breaches
in its observance, and fight the wars of God, we may, with assurance,
consider him Mashiach.
If he succeeds in the above, builds the Temple in its place, and
gathers the dispersed of Israel, he is definitely the Mashiach.
He will then improve the entire world, motivating all the nations to
serve God together, as Tzephaniah 3:9 states: "I will transform the
peoples to a purer language that they all will call upon the name of
God and serve Him with one purpose."
If he did not succeed to this degree or was killed, he surely is not
the redeemer promised by the Torah. Rather, he should be considered as
all the other proper and complete kings of the Davidic dynasty who
died. God caused him to arise only to test the many, as Daniel 11:35
states: "And some of the wise men will stumble, to try them, to
refine, and to clarify until the appointed time, because the set time
is in the future."
Jesus of Nazareth who aspired to be the Mashiach and was executed by
the court was also alluded to in Daniel's prophecies, as ibid. 11:14
states: "The vulgar among your people shall exalt themselves in an
attempt to fulfill the vision, but they shall stumble."
Can there be a greater stumbling block than Christianity? All the
prophets spoke of Mashiach as the redeemer of Israel and their savior
who would gather their dispersed and strengthen their observance of
the mitzvot. In contrast, Christianity caused the Jews to be slain by
the sword, their remnants to be scattered and humbled, the Torah to be
altered, and the majority of the world to err and serve a god other
than the Lord.
Nevertheless, the intent of the Creator of the world is not within the
power of man to comprehend, for His ways are not our ways, nor are His
thoughts, our thoughts. Ultimately, all the deeds of Jesus of Nazareth
and that Ishmaelite who arose after him will only serve to prepare the
way for Mashiach's coming and the improvement of the entire world,
motivating the nations to serve God together as Tzephaniah 3:9 states:
"I will transform the peoples to a purer language that they all will
call upon the name of God and serve Him with one purpose."
How will this come about? The entire world has already become filled
with the mention of Mashiach, Torah, and mitzvot. These matters have
been spread to the furthermost islands to many stubborn-hearted
nations. They discuss these matters and the mitzvot of the Torah,
saying: "These mitzvot were true, but were already negated in the
present age and are not applicable for all time."
Others say: "Implied in the mitzvot are hidden concepts that can not
be understood simply. The Mashiach has already come and revealed those
hidden truths."
When the true Messianic king will arise and prove successful, his
position becoming exalted and uplifted, they will all return and
realize that their ancestors endowed them with a false heritage and
their prophets and ancestors caused them to err.
ד וְאִם יַעֲמֹד מֶלֶךְ מִבֵּית דָּוִד הוֹגֶה בַּתּוֹרָה וְעוֹסֵק
בְּמִצְוֹת כְּדָוִד אָבִיו. כְּפִי תּוֹרָה שֶׁבִּכְתָב וְשֶׁבְּעַל
פֶּה. וְיָכֹף כָּל יִשְׂרָאֵל לֵילֵךְ בָּהּ וּלְחַזֵּק בִּדְקָהּ.
וְיִלָּחֵם מִלְחֲמוֹת ה'. הֲרֵי זֶה בְּחֶזְקַת שֶׁהוּא מָשִׁיחַ. (אִם
עָשָׂה וְהִצְלִיחַ וּבָנָה מִקְדָּשׁ בִּמְקוֹמוֹ וְקִבֵּץ נִדְחֵי
יִשְׂרָאֵל הֲרֵי זֶה מָשִׁיחַ בְּוַדַּאי. וִיתַקֵּן אֶת הָעוֹלָם
כֻּלּוֹ לַעֲבֹד אֶת ה' בְּיַחַד שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר "כִּי אָז אֶהְפֹּךְ אֶל
עַמִּים שָׂפָה בְרוּרָה לִקְרֹא כֻלָּם בְּשֵׁם ה' וּלְעָבְדוֹ שְׁכֶם
אֶחָד"):
וְאִם לֹא הִצְלִיחַ עַד כֹּה, אוֹ נֶהֱרָג, בְּיָדוּעַ שֶׁאֵינוֹ זֶה
שֶׁהִבְטִיחָה עָלָיו תּוֹרָה, וַהֲרֵי הוּא כְּכָל מַלְכֵי בֵּית דָּוִד
הַשְּׁלֵמִים הַכְּשֵׁרִים שֶׁמֵּתוּ. וְלֹא הֶעֱמִידוֹ הַקָּדוֹשׁ
בָּרוּךְ הוּא אֶלָּא לְנַסּוֹת בּוֹ רַבִּים, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר "וּמִן
הַמַּשְׂכִּילִים יִכָּשְׁלוּ לִצְרוֹף בָּהֶן וּלְבָרֵר וְלַלְבֵּן עַד
עֵת קֵץ כִּי עוֹד לַמּוֹעֵד".
אַף יֵשׁוּעַ הַנּוֹצְרִי שֶׁדִּימָה שֶׁיִּהְיֶה מָשִׁיחַ, וְנֶהֱרָג
בְּבֵית דִּין, כְּבָר נִתְנַבֵּא בּוֹ דָּנִיֵּאל, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר "וּבְנֵי
פָּרִיצֵי עַמְּךָ יִנַּשְּׂאוּ לְהַעֲמִיד חָזוֹן וְנִכְשָׁלוּ" (דניאל
יא, יד). וְכִי יֵשׁ מִכְשׁוֹל גָּדוֹל מִזֶּה, שֶׁכָּל הַנְּבִיאִים
דִּבְּרוּ שֶׁהַמָּשִׁיחַ גּוֹאֵל יִשְׂרָאֵל וּמוֹשִׁיעָם, וּמְקַבֵּץ
נִדְחֵיהֶם וּמְחַזֵּק מִצְוָתָן, וְזֶה גָּרַם לְאַבֵּד יִשְׂרָאֵל
בַּחֶרֶב, וּלְפַזֵּר שְׁאֵרִיתָם וּלְהַשְׁפִּילָם, וּלְהַחֲלִיף
הַתּוֹרָה, וּלְהַטְעוֹת רוֹב הָעוֹלָם לַעֲבֹד אֱלוֹהַּ מִבַּלְעֲדֵי
ה'.
אֲבָל מַחְשְׁבוֹת בּוֹרֵא עוֹלָם אֵין כּוֹחַ בָּאָדָם לְהַשִּׂיגָם,
כִּי לֹא דְּרָכֵינוּ דְּרָכָיו וְלֹא מַחְשְׁבוֹתֵינוּ מַחְשְׁבוֹתָיו.
וְכָל הַדְּבָרִים הָאֵלּוּ שֶׁל יֵשׁוּעַ הַנּוֹצְרִי, וְשֶׁל זֶה
הַיִּשְׁמְעֵאלִי שֶׁעָמַד אַחֲרָיו, אֵינָן אֶלָּא לְיַשֵּׁר דֶּרֶךְ
לַמֶּלֶךְ הַמָּשִׁיחַ, וּלְתַקֵּן אֶת הָעוֹלָם כֻּלּוּ לַעֲבֹד אֶת ה'
בְּיַחַד: שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר "כִּי אָז אֶהְפֹּךְ אֶל עַמִּים שָׂפָה בְרוּרָה
לִקְרֹא כֻּלָּם בְּשֵׁם ה' וּלְעוֹבְדוֹ שְׁכֶם אֶחָד" (ראה צפניה ג,
ט).
כֵּיצַד: כְּבָר נִתְמַלֵּא הָעוֹלָם כֻּלּוֹ מִדִּבְרֵי הַמָּשִׁיחַ,
וּמִדִּבְרֵי הַתּוֹרָה וּמִדִּבְרֵי הַמִּצְווֹת, וּפָשְׁטוּ דְּבָרִים
אֵלּוּ בְּאִיִּים רְחוֹקִים, וּבְעַמִּים רַבִּים עַרְלֵי לֵב; וְהֵם
נוֹשְׂאִים וְנוֹתְנִים בִּדְבָרִים אֵלּוּ וּבְמִצְווֹת הַתּוֹרָה,
אֵלּוּ אוֹמְרִים מִצְווֹת אֵלּוּ אֱמֶת הָיוּ, וּכְבָר בָּטְלוּ
בַּזְּמַן הַזֶּה, וְלֹא הָיוּ נוֹהֲגוֹת לְדוֹרוֹת. וְאֵלּוּ אוֹמְרִים
דְּבָרִים נִסְתָּרוֹת יֵשׁ בָּהֶם, וְאֵינָן כִּפְשׁוּטָן, וּכְבָר בָּא
מָשִׁיחַ, וְגִלָּה נִסְתְּרֵיהֶם.
וּכְשֶׁיַּעֲמוֹד הַמֶּלֶךְ הַמָּשִׁיחַ בֶּאֱמֶת, וְיַצְלִיחַ וְיָרוּם
וְיִינָשֵׂא, מִיַּד הֵם כּוּלָן חוֹזְרִין וְיוֹדְעִים שֶׁשֶּׁקֶר
נָחֲלוּ אֲבוֹתֵיהֶם, וְשֶׁנְּבִיאֵיהֶם וַאֲבוֹתֵיהֶם הִטְעוּם.

In Melachim uMilchamot - Chapter 11.
He first says that Moshiach needs to be a King from the house of David, as well as do certain specific things, to qualify as Moshiach.
Then he says that Yushkuh is clearly not Moshiach, because he didn't do the things that are required.
Why not simply state that Yushkuh is not descended from King David, and therefore is automatically disqualified, regardless of what he did?

That would imply he was fit to be moshiach except for a technicality.

@shmosel but the main requirement is that Moshiach has to be descended from King David, if anything all of the other things are "technicalities"

How do you know he wasn't a descendant?

@DoubleAA according to their theory his father wasn't.

... and we don't believe in virgin birth, so perhaps his real father was in fact Davidic? That's DoubleAA's point. But what we do know is that his accomplishments didn't meet our requirements.

@Shalom but the Rambam is speaking to those who did think he was Moshiach, who (seemingly?) do Believe that

@Awtsmoos--עצמות if I am trying to convince those who did think that, then arguing something I can not prove, will be fruitless. I argue the visible lack of specific required results and they will have less ability to answer.

@rosends there's no need to prove it, they themselves are claiming it
